# No sudo permissions on google CentOS VM

Tags: linux, centos, passwords, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

It is suposed that every user in the VM created on the Google Cloud Platform has root permissions, but I haven't been able to do anything, because it says that my user has no permissions and I don't have any password, either for my user, or for root.

Is there any default password for root, or any way I could find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well i have virtual machine with ubuntu (i presume that it is the same for other linux distros as well)  : login to your Google Cloud platform -> VM Instances -> click on you instance (virtual machine) , click on SSH button which is on left upper corner and for example pick a frist option Open in browser window.. when the windows opens you will be logged in as regular user with sudo permission. After that you can create users etc.. If you want to use other ssh client then go to

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#standardssh

it well written documentation.. the most "complicated" will be to create key pairs .. if you still have problems just ask :)